# How to check UUID null value in JPQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am using JPA/Hibernate. So I wanna to do nullCheck in JPQL, but when I do that it does not determine dataType.

JPQL Query:

```
  @Query("select a from Attribute a where :attributeId is null OR a.id = :attributeId")
  Page<Attribute> findByAttributeId(@Param("attributeId") UUUID attributeId);
```

EXCEPTION:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not
> determine data type of parameter $1
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:153)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:103)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor582.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy398.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
> ... 114 common frames omitted

I searched a lot on Internet on this topic, but can not find soluthion.
I do not want to handle it in service layer.

I tried:

1. PostgreSql CAST function
2. check as String
3. @Type annotation.

Is there anyway to check UUID null Value in JPQL?

Comment: Add also the method declaration if repository interface.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @pirho Sorry, I forget that.

Comment: @cjgmj Sometimes, attributeId come as null. I do not wanna handle it in servise layer, as all nullchecks in application was handled in queries. For consistency reason, i wanna handle it in query

Comment: but if you id is null you have to return the objects from db with id null?

Comment: @cjgmj  :attributeId is null condition will meet this case, if it is possible to nullcheck UUId)

Comment: What do you expect when te attributeId is null? You want to get the Attributes with id null? If its the case, you have to change the SQL for `select a from Attribute a where a.id is null OR a.id = :attributeId`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit investigation on Internet, I found the solution.
As PostgreSQL can not determine dataType, we can declare it from before as TypedParameterValue.

```
TypedParameterValue attributeId = new TypedParameterValue(PostgresUUIDType.INSTANCE, UUIDUtil.toUUID(attributeId));
Page<Attribute> attributes = attributeRepo.findByAttributeId(attributeId);
```

Then in JPQL for nullChecking, cast to org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType:
( In IDE, it can be shown as error, but it compiles actually)

```
 @Query("select a from Attribute a where (cast(:attributeId as org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType) OR a.id = :attributeId)")
 Page<Attribute> findByAttributeId(@Param("attributeId") TypedParameterValue attributeId);
```

In Native Query:

```
 @Query(value = "select * from attribute a where (cast(:attributeId as uuid) OR a.id = :attributeId)",nativeQuery = true)
 List<Attribute> findByAttributeId(@Param("attributeId") TypedParameterValue attributeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with JPA 3.0 + EclipseLink + PostgreSQL and was caused because something about automatic casting of parameters. Try adding a `stringtype=unspecified` to your connection URL:
`jdbc:postgresql://SERVER:5432/mydatabase?stringtype=unspecified`

Comment: Actuallly, I connect to postgre as this